# not able to scrape the data and even the links are not changing while clciking on pagination using python

Tags: python-3.x

want to **scrape** data from of each block and want to change the pages, but not able to do that,help me someone to crack this.

i tried to crawl data using headers and form data , but fail to do that.
below is my code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

url='http://www.msmemart.com/msme/listings/company-list/agriculture-product-stocks/1/585/Supplier'


headers={
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",

    "Cookie": "unique_visitor=49.35.36.33; __utma=189548087.1864205671.1549441624.1553842230.1553856136.3; __utmc=189548087; __utmz=189548087.1553856136.3.3.utmcsr=nsic.co.in|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/; csrf=d665df0941bbf3bce09d1ee4bd2b079e; ci_session=ac6adsb1eb2lcoogn58qsvbjkfa1skhv; __utmt=1; __utmb=189548087.26.10.1553856136",

    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36",

    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",

    "Accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
    
    }
data ={
    
    'catalog': 'Supplier',
    'category':'1',
    'subcategory':'585',
    'type': 'company-list',
    'csrf': '0db0757db9473e8e5169031b7164f2a4'

    } 
r = requests.get(url,data=data,headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

div = soup.find('div',{"id":"listings_result"})

for prod in div.find_all('b',string='Products/Services:').next_sibling:

      print(prod)
```

getting "ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" 2-3 times, i want to crawl all text details in a block.plz someone help me to found this.

Comment: at what line are you getting the ConnectionResetError error? why are you making a 2nd request get?

Comment: I remove the first requests.get and then run it but getting same error multiple times  and error occurs at this point "r = requests.get(url,data=data,headers=headers)",help me to get this.